# Select the value of a static select list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

On my home page I have a search form where people can search for houses. It redirects to a controller and action which searches for houses and shows them in a View.

On the result View I have a several lists like this.

```
<select name="priceFrom">
    <option value="0">€0</option>
    <option value="100000">€100.000</option>
    <option value="200000">€200.000</option>
</select>
```

The View contains a model: `@model Irrelevant.Namespace.ViewModels.SearchResults`

I want to select the value they chose on the home page, it's stored in the SearchResults ViewModel. In WebForms I used to do `Bind()` or `Eval()`, is there any equivalent in MVC which offers a clean way to accomplish this?

Comment: Which property of SearchResults class maps to the selected value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SelectListItem` has a `Selected` property, which will be respected by `Html.DropDownListFor<>()`.

If you are manually declaring the markup for your `selects`, you end up with a functional but much less elegant solution, such as:

```
<select name="priceFrom">
    <option value="0">€0</option>
    <option value="100000" @(Model.SomeCondition ? "selected" : "" )>€100.000</option>
    <option value="200000" @(Model.SomeCondition ? "selected" : "" )>€200.000</option>
</select>
```

Remember, the presence of the `selected` attribute may cause the user agent to treat is as "true".

Ideally, all of your dropdown lists would be generated from your view model. When your view model is created, you would evaluate previous conditions (such as a selection on another page) and set `Selected` on the appropriate item.

Comment: Are you recommending to generate a `SelectList` in my ViewModel, select the item in my Controller and use `Html.DropDownList()` in my View?

Comment: Yes, that may be a cleaner way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

you have to do the below for all the options

```
<select name="priceFrom">
   <option value="0" @(Model.PriceFrom.ToString().Equals("0") ? "selected":"")>€0</option>
   <option value="100000" @(Model.PriceFrom.ToString().Equals("100000") ? "selected":"")>€100.000</option>
   ...
</select>
```

There is one more way in MVC that can take advantage of `@Html.DropDownListFor` method where you need to have a list property in your model that can be directly bind to the Dropdownlist with the specified selected value